# CRM 2011 Email in Workflow

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a problem in the crm2011 on premises deployement. I used to have a process that waits 15 days before a contract ends and sends an email to the user that created it and his manager .

The process stopped working a month ago and while checking why i noticed that all attributes in the mail (usually highlited in yellow) are gone and i can't add them anymore.

I tried creating a new process to check if the process is corrupted but i encountered the same problem with all entities when sending an email (Check image). On the other side it works when creating or updating a record.

The Entity related is Contract .

The scope is the Organization.

We don't use an email router.

And the Start when is when a Record is Created.

http://postimg.org/image/3zsyz5mn1/

Comment: I sometimes have problems with the workflow editor in IE, have you tried out firefox?

Obvious answer I know, but it's best to check all bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the exact same issue working with CRM 2011 on IE 11 - compatibility mode didn't make any difference. Try using an older version of IE (I used IE 8 which was installed on the server).

Once you make the edits, the WF will work even though it doesn't show on the IE 11 machines.

Comment: Thanks this was the problem